# Problema con Error en php

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Me sale este error en PHP

```
Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given inC:\xampp\htdocs\androide_datos\listar.php on line 
 12
{"frutas":[]}
```

asi debería salirme:

```
 {"frutas":[{"id":"48","nombre":"manzana","10-12-17 24:3"}
```

My codigo completo es esto

```
<?php
//  include_once './conexion.php';
      include 'conexion.php';
    $respuesta = array();
    $respuesta["frutas"] = array();  

// Conectarse al servidor y seleccionar base de datos.
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysqli_select_db($con,"$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM info";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        // Array temporal para crear una sola categoría
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["id"] = $row["id"];
        $tmp["nombre"] = $row["dato"];
        $tmp["fecha"] = $row["fecha"];

        // Push categoría a final json array
        array_push($respuesta["frutas"], $tmp);
    }

    // Mantener el encabezado de respuesta a json
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    //Escuchando el resultado de json
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba reemplazando lo siguiente:

```
// Array temporal para crear una sola categoría:
$tmp = array();
$tmp["id"] = $row[0];
$tmp["nombre"] = $row[1];
$tmp["fecha"] = $row[2];
```

Comment: sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Lo único que quieres es mostrar un resultado? Si es así prueba con esto

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        // Array temporal para crear una sola categoría
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["id"] = $row["id"];
        $tmp["nombre"] = $row["dato"];
        $tmp["fecha"] = $row["fecha"];

        // Push categoría a final json array
        array_push($respuesta["frutas"], $tmp);
    }

Comment: sale error en array    -> syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY)

Comment: Exactamente como deseas mostrar el resultado de la consulta? Lo quieres mostrar a través de una tabla?

Comment: asi lo quiero mostrar {"frutas":[{"id":"48","nombre":"manzana","10-12-17 24:3"}

Comment: ya lo solucione el error estaba en la conexion

Comment: @AyrtonAxel responde tu propia pregunta y acéptala. Kabr, debes [edit] tu respuesta - los comentarios son temporales.